# PHP7.0 removing variables with if statements?

Tags: php, php-7.0

So here's more or less what I have going:

```
<?php
....
$examplevar = $_POST['examplevar'];
if ($examplevar === NULL) {
    die('fatal error: null value');
} else {
.......
?>
```

On this script, 100% of the time I get the "fatal error"
If however I change it slightly

```
<?php
.....
$examplevar = $_POST['examplevar'];
die($examplevar);
?>
```

It prints the correct string with no issue

This is absolutely baffling to me.

I also then tried:

```
<?php
....
$examplevar = $_POST['examplevar'];
if (1==1) {
    die('Your input: '.$examplevar);
}
?>
```

Which returns "Your input: "
and no further text

I'm absolutely out of ideas. Any help would be massively appreciated

PHP7.0 on Apache2 on Debian 9

Comment: Have you tried removing everything else, leaving only the parts you've shown in your question?

Comment: Test the $_POST super-global for any content: `var_dump($_POST);`, are you accessing the script via a HTTP POST?

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` at the beginning of your script to see what's in the array.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) should return an empty array if there is nothing in it, could you be overwriting it somewhere else? check your comparations if maybe there is a = sign where a === should be

Comment: That's both not likely, nor specific to PHP 7.0 (albeit the SAPI might be relevant). Showcase the `...` part, and a screenshot of the request from your browser developer tools. And of course enable `error_reporting` as always when something doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

use `empty()` to check `$_POST['your name']` isset or not and if isset that is empty or not